# Javascript Moment Invalid Date Error on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to reformat dates to another language using moment, It works on Chrome and Edge but apparently it is not working on Internet explorer as it returns **Invalid Date**. Please see code below.

```
moment.locale('ja);    
moment('Jan 05').format('MMM DD');
```

Comment: Internet explorer which version please

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 2):

Yes, creating a moment from a string does not work the same in all browsers. The documentation warns against doing this. If you need consistent parsing, you should instead specify what the format of the string is. For example:

```
moment('01-05-2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
```

For more information, see documentation [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)